# How to add title name to each div item and display 5 div item in a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, pagination

I am calling getjson multiple times using "for loop" and get response back and want to display the items on sale inside a div. Currently my code displays the item name just to the right of each frame but i want to the item name below the iframe just like the block of code show below:

**sample div item that want to output instead of what my code outputs currently but dont know how**:

```
<li>
       <iframe src='http://bsite.com/itemshow.php?pen' height=200 width=200 style='border: none;'></iframe><br>
        <div class="details">
        <div class="title">
          <a href="/pen/">pen</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

could you guys tell me how i can add item name below each dive item(just like above block of code) and limit the number of divs to 5 per row ?

part of code that display the div currently:

```
var siteContents2 = "<iframe src='http://bsite.com/itemshow.php?"+itemName' height=200 width=200 style='border: none;'></iframe>"+itemName;

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += siteContents2;
```

full code:

```
function GetJSONResult(itemName)
{
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://asite.com/checkit.php'+ itemName + '/&callback=?', function(data){

       var siteContents = data.contents;      
  //writes to textarea  
  document.myform.outputtext.value = siteContents ;  

var n=siteContents.search("This item is not on sale");

if(n===-1)
    {
     //alert("This item is on sale. n:"+n);

var siteContents2 = "<iframe src='http://bsite.com/itemshow.php?"+itemName' height=200 width=200 style='border: none;'></iframe>"+itemName;

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += siteContents2;
};
});  

};

items=["pen","book","paper","ink","tshirt","map"];

for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
{
//document.write(i+")"+items[i] + "<br>");

GetJSONResult(items[i]);
}


</script>   
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: seems u r missing `+` after `itemName` and before and after `border: none;`

Comment: that is not the issue. I dont know how to add the itme name below the iframe.Now it displays it to the right of each iframe. I want output it like the sample in the top

Comment: as i understand from you question, you can do that using css by setting the width of the div to 100%.

Comment: thanks for reply. But how to print those blocks of div elements inside jquery in the first place before i use css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace your iframe with more complex html I think you just need to extend your string

```
var siteContents2 = "<li>"
   +"<iframe src='http://bsite.com/itemshow.php?"+itemName+"' height=200 width=200 style='border: none;'></iframe><br>"
   +"<div class='details'>"
   +"<div class='title'>"
   +"<a href='/"+itemName+"/'>"+itemName+"</a>"
   +"</div></div></li>";
```

then append these contents to myDiv as you did, though I would recommend to do that with jquery as you're already using it

```
$("#myDiv").append(siteContents2);
```

Also, your myDiv probably should be a UL or OL list, not a DIV as you want to append list items to it.

To make your li items to be displayed 5 items per row you can apply appropriate css styling for them, for example make them float:left, and set parent ul width to fit 5 items (so that next 5 would go to next row), see this simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/Qnbk4/

```
#myDiv{
    width:500px;
}
#myDiv li{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
```

Of course you need to adpat this to fit your code

Comment: Thanks . Now i got the iframe title below each iframe!could you tell me how i append these blocks of <li></li> so they get arranged in rows of 5 . Now they are printed one below each other! Furthermore,what you mean mean my div should UL or OL list ? how to make it UL or OL list >

Comment: I updated answer to limit your GetJSONResult function call to 5 times.
As for ul or ol list, I mean your myDiv element looks like <div id="myDiv">, but as it contans li items it needs to be ul or ol list bo be a proper html markup like <ul id="myDiv"></ul>

Comment: I changed it to <ul id="myDiv"></ul>.May be i didn't explain correctly. I don't want to limit number of calls to 5. What i want is to display each  <li></li> in rows of 5( 5 sets of <li>...</li> in one row) not just below each other. Now if i call the function 20 times. All iframes display one below each other but i want them to show 5 per row.

Comment: paulitto many thanks for clear explanation. It worked well:-)